# javascript window confirm pops up several times

Tags: javascript, confirm

i am trying to use the confirm method but for some reason the confirm window pops up several times. I googled and tried different things but unfortunately I can't get it running properly. The code is the following:

```
//user clicks on the delete button
$("#deletePopUpImage").click(function(){

        console.log("deletePopUpimageCalled");

        //get the id of the image
        id = ($(this).parent().prop("id"));

        //create the ajax request
        data = "typ=function&functionType=deleteUserImage&id="+id;

        //open the confirm box
        var r = confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete this image?");
        if (r == true) {
            console.log("loadAjaxCAlled");

            //Ajax call
            loadAjax(data);

            //hide the image and the loader
            hideImagePopup();
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }  
    });
```

The strange thing is that sometimes the confirm window pops up twice, sometimes three times and sometimes as expected once. That's why inserted the two console.logs.

"deletePopUpimageCalled" always appears just once. However "loadAjaxCAlled" appears several times.

In the success callback of the Ajax request I am just hiding the thumbnail div.

Do you know what's wrong with my code above?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: you might have clicking image `twice` or `thrice` accidently. Disable the click on your `first click` and check the result

Comment: Have your tried calling the ajax method in the callback instead?

Comment: @RajeevKumar how would I disable the click events? By adding the attribute disabled via jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the code that attaches the event:

```
$("#deletePopUpImage").click(function(){...});
```

is invoked several times. Every invocation of .click(...) makes a new handler that fires when the button is clicked.

Some browsers stack up log the same entries into one (so the log doesn't extend so fast), that could be the reason you don't see "deletePopUpimageCalled" many times.
It would the best to check this by debugging it in the browser.

Comment: That would mean several "deletePopUpImageCalled".

Comment: @Quentin Roy - some browsers stack the same entries up so you have just one entry

Comment: Fair point. Though usually you do see the number of times it has been received in the form of a number at the left of the console entry. Also, in that case, why does he get several "loadAjaxCAlled"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments! I agree with Roy. Why are there severals loadAjaxCAlled but only one deletePopUpimageCalled. This means that there was only one click event fired in my eyes. There is certainly only one loadAjaxCalled! I am confused ^^

Comment: Ok, what if you change "console.log("deletePopUpimageCalled");" into alert("deletePopUpimageCalled2");? JS is synchronous, I don't expect any weird behaviour from confirm() method.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The strange thing is, that I couldn't reproduce the issue now. Now it also works with console.log. There must be something wrong with another part of the code I think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. In the Ajax success handler I set the div of the image, that was deleted, to display:none instead of deleting it. Thus divIds could occur twice, three times, etc. After changing the code to delete, it worked smoothly.